# DBLink from Oracle to Cassandra

Tags: oracle, cassandra, dblink

For a training purpose, I am trying create a DBLink between Oracle 12c and Cassandra 3.9.0, both installed on local machine.

For this I performed the steps described in this [link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-odbc-oracle-hs.rst).
Unfortunately, in the end I finished with error message:

```
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
Unable to retrieve columns for table [LOCAL]. {42000,NativeErr = -1}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from TO_CASSANDRA
28500. 00000 -  "connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:"
*Cause:    The cause is explained in the forwarded message.
*Action:   See the non-Oracle system's documentation of the forwarded
           message.
```

Can you give me some hints about what I am doing wrong, please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The solution is more easier than I expected.
When I received the error, I used the following statement:

> SELECT * from emp@mycassandradb WHERE empid = 1;

... and to solve it I used:

> SELECT * from "emp"@mycassandradb WHERE "empid" = 1;

Hope it might be helpful for some others,